# How to determine scale of a rotated plane so that its 2D dimension matches a given input

Tags: 3d, geometry, 2d

I should start off with saying I'm a total noob when it comes to math and geometry. It wasn't my best subject in school.

The end goal I have is thus:

I want to take a list of facial landmarks combined with pose and determine what the actual width of the face is, even if it's rotated.

I'm guessing the easiest solution is to measure from the tip of the nose to which ever side of the face that is most visible, then apply the Euler orientation to a line, and determine the scale factor that makes the line match the landmarks, then multiple the scale to the line length to get half the face width, then multiply by two to get the whole face width.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks!

-- edit --

The landmarks are 2D and the library provides the pose for the head as 3D Euler rotations.

The end goal is to place 3D elements on the user's face akin to SnapChat. We need to scale the objects to match the user's head. To do this, we'd need to measure the width of their face, which cannot be done easily if the user's head isn't straight. I want to take the 3D pose that is provided, combine it with the landmarks and determine what width of the user's face would be.

Comment: Are your landmarks 2D or 3D? Is the pose a 3D rotation of the head? Do you have camera calibration information? I don't really get your proposal. What do you want to rotate and why? Rotations preserve length. Can you illustrate the idea?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks! I've edited my post. I don't know what you mean by "camera calibration information."

Comment: Do you know how to project 3D points onto the 2D image? That's what I meant by calibration. Your 2D landmarks do not have depth then?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Correct, I don’t have depth on the landmarks. As far as camera calibration, I looked into it a little and it seems like it may be safe to assume no distortion and a fov calculated from the image with and height.

Comment: You cannot calculate fov from width and height. How do you intend to do that?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I don't know. I read an article that described something like that. https://www.learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/ Section titled "Intrinsic parameters of the camera"